# How to copy/move AcroForm fields from one document to new blank one using IText5 or IText7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to copy whole `AcroForm` including field positions and values from template PDF to a new blank PDF file. How can I do that?

In short words - I need to get rid of "background" from the template and leave only filed forms.
The whole point of this is to create a PDF with content that would be printed on pre-printed templates.

I am using IText 5 but I can switch to 7 if usefull examples would be provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I have found the solution to "How to copy AcfroForm fields into another PDF". It is a iText v7 version. I hope it will help somebody someday.

```
private byte[] copyFormElements(byte[] sourceTemplate) throws IOException {
    PdfReader completeReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(sourceTemplate));
    PdfDocument completeDoc = new PdfDocument(completeReader);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter offsetWriter = new PdfWriter(out);
    PdfDocument offsetDoc = new PdfDocument(offsetWriter);
    offsetDoc.initializeOutlines();
    PdfPage blank = offsetDoc.addNewPage();
    PdfAcroForm originalForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(completeDoc, false);
    //      originalForm.getPdfObject().copyTo(offsetDoc,false);
    PdfAcroForm offsetForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(offsetDoc, true);

    for (String name : originalForm.getFormFields().keySet()) {
        PdfFormField field = originalForm.getField(name);
        PdfDictionary copied = field.getPdfObject().copyTo(offsetDoc, false);
        PdfFormField copiedField = PdfFormField.makeFormField(copied, offsetDoc);
        offsetForm.addField(copiedField, blank);
    }

    offsetDoc.close();
    completeDoc.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [PdfCopyForms](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopyForms.html) object:

> Allows you to add one (or more) existing PDF document(s) to create a new PDF and add the form of another PDF document to this new PDF.

I didn't find an example, but you could try something like this:

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(src1); // a document with a form
PdfReader reader2 = new PdfReader(src2); // a document without a form
PdfCopyForms copy = new PdfCopyForms(new FileOutputStream(dest));
copy.AddDocument(reader1); // add the document without the form
copy.CopyDocumentFields(reader2); // add the fields of the document with the form
copy.close();
reader1.close();
reader2.close();
```

I see that the class is deprecated. I'm not sure of that's because iText 7 makes it much easier to do this, or if it's because there were technical problems with the class.

Comment: Will give it a try. Stay tuned for results :)

Comment: can you provide example for IText7? I am getting indirect reference exception while trying to make copy of fields using IText7